# Solving the subset sum problem by picking one number from each of four sets

Tags: python, numpy

I am building a multi-dimensional query, which in this example we can use 3 input arrays of Amount, however the number of input arrays will vary (by increments of 4) i.e: 4,8,12,16 etc.

It is very important to note that each number in each array will be larger than the previous one, and seeing as we are using base10 (decimal) for the math, the scale of increase will be 1.

I need to return a single result of "Amount" from each array of double "Amount", where they add up to "TotalAmount".

```
Input: at least 4 arrays of Double, and TotalAmount. 
Output: at least 4 results, (matching amount as number of input arrays), equaling TotalAmount.
```

Simple Example using three arrays of three items each.
For this example, the Match Value must be within the boundaries of 6-18, one result for each row.

```
Match Value: 14

Arrays:

[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
```

The correct answer would return 5 results:

```
[1,4,9],
[1,5,8],
[2,4,8], 
[2,5,7],
[3,4,7]
```

I have tried every other form of this: O(n^2), lambda expressions, if then for loops, various forms of subset sum and dynamic sql queries, and I'm looking into numpy, the python science library for some ideas or answers.
So far, it always ends up being so time intensive for large queries in up to 50+ arrays, that it was prohibitive.

I have a concept, where the slices of each array are done in a cross cut fashion. so that the end result is equalization of the results in each array, or the closest angle towards balance, with refinement resulting in Zero.

Slicing it horizontally will never provide the result needed, as each match must be from a separate array. It does provide a baseline for the slice.

```
[1,2,3]=6
[4,5,6]=15
[7,8,9] =24
```

Slicing it vertically provides a possible result set, but also gives a baseline of the minimum and maximum range of possibilities, 12-18:

```
[1,4,7]=12
[2,5,8]=15
[3,6,9]=18
```

with crosscut as a curve providing an even middle ground between it for comparison:

```
[1,5,9]=15
[4,5,6]=15
[7,5,3]=15
```

funny enough, none of these will result in 14.

Shown in a grid of 4 arrays of 4 values, where the Answer would be between 28 and 40:

```
Array Totals         Cross Cut            Array Slices

[01,02,03,04] = 10   [01,06,11,16] = 34   [01,05,09,13] = 28
[05,06,07,08] = 26   [02,06,11,15] = 34   [02,06,10,14] = 32
[09,10,11,12] = 42   [03,07,10,14] = 34   [03,07,11,15] = 36
[13,14,15,16] = 58   [04,07,10,13] = 34   [04,08,12,16] = 40
```

However the 4 arrays can have a different depth, such as this 4 array, with a depth of 8, with Answers lying within 52-80:

```
Arrays                    Total    Crosscut

[01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08] =  36   [01,10,23,32] = 66
[09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] = 100   [02,11,22,31] = 66
[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24] = 164   [03,12,21,30] = 66
[25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32] = 228   [04,12,21,29] = 66
 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --    ---   [05,13,20,28] = 66
 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80  = 528   [06,14,19,27] = 66
                                  [07,14,19,26] = 66
                                  [08,15,18,25] = 66
```

Interesting to note that 528 is sum of both ways, and the crosscut is always consistently 1/8th of the sum, 66, or that fraction of the total.

That resulting "tolerance away from zero" could be adjusted towards zero for the difference of the result and the Answer, like an audio equalizer for sound balancing, but with numbers..

can something similar be applied to this problem?

Comment: Can you explain the current algorithm you're using, show the code you're using, and give an example input which is too slow under your approach?

Comment: There is no simple answer to this problem, it's not an issue of syntax. You have to think about a good algorithm to solve this problem efficiently, in any language. The naive approach (enumerate all combinations and keep the ones with the right sum) has exponential complexity over the number of input arrays, which obviously will be too expensive in any programming language. This problem asks you to devise a better algorithm than that.